# Add a calculated column with if statements

Tags: sharepoint-server, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

New in this forum. And I have a quick question:
I have a choice column with this values:

Kg

Lb

Ton

And I would like to add a column that multiplies if I choose Kg or Lb or Ton and convert everything to Lb:

Kg to Lb Rate = 2.2046

Lb to Lb      = 1

Lb to Ton     = 2000

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What is the meaning of " if I choose Kg or Lb or Ton and convert everything to Lb Kg to Lb Rate = 2.2046 Lb to Kb = 1 Lb to Ton = 2000"? Please describe it a little bit clearly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly then you want to convert your value column in "Lb" unit based on the choice column.

Consider,

`[Unit Column]` --> Choice column with choices: Kg, Ton, Lb

`[Another Column]` --> Column which contains actual value

Then use below formula:

```
=IF([Unit Column]="Kg", [Another Column] * 2.2046, IF([Unit Column]="Ton", [Another Column] * 2000, [Another Column] * 1))
```

Instead of `[Another Column] * 1`, you can also use only `[Another Column]` (I have added it just for better understanding).

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Make sure your value column (`[Another Column]`) is of **Number** data type.
3. Return your calculated field as **Number**.

**official documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)).
2. [IF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-7025be14-5665-43d0-af20-8293d1fe9d3a).